# why identical() return true on two strings

Tags: dart

I'm new to Dart. The documentation say: "To test whether two objects x and y represent the same thing, use the == operator. (In the rare case where you need to know whether two objects are the exact same object, use the identical() function instead.)"

So, if type this code:

```dart
var foo = 'bar';
var baz = 'bar';
print(identical(foo, baz));
```

If i've well understood, foo and bar do not reference the same object. So identical() must return false, isn't it ?
But it's not the case, at least in DartPad.

Where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For several built-in "literals", you will always get identical `true` for equal values.

- bool
- String
- int
- double (I think)

Answer (score 3):

In this case `foo` and `bar` do reference the same object.
That is because the compiler *canonicalizes* string literals.

The specification requires most constants to be canonicalized. If you create `const Duration(seconds: 1)` in two places, it will become the *same* object. Integers, doubles and booleans are always canonicalized, whether constant or not (the language pretends that there is only one instance per value).

Strings are special in that the specification is not entirely clear on whether they need to be canonicalized or not, but *constant* strings *need* to be canonicalized for constants to make sense, and all the compilers do that. 
A literal is a constant expression, so string literals are always canonicalized. That means that `'bar'` denotes the same object no matter where it occurs in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I build the string by code (for example using a simple List : var chars = ['b','a','r'];, then applying the same loop on the two variables : chars.forEach((item)  {foo += item;});  chars.forEach((item)  {baz += item;});   "identical" return true again, whilst it's not literals now. Strange.

Comment: If you are compiling the code to JavaScript, then any equal strings are also identical. That's because JavaScript does not provide any way to distinguish two strings with the same content. The Dart compiler compiles `identical(a, b)` to the JavaScript `a === b` and equal strings are also `===` in JavaScript.
If the code is run on the VM, those two strings will likely not be identical.